# NuxtJs Local Storage related issue during SSR mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-router

```
middleware ({ store, redirect }) {
    if (process.client && Session.IsLoggedIn()) {
      return redirect(`/${Session.GetPermission()}`)
    }
  }
```

So I am using this middleware function at the homepage(`/`) of my site. It was working well in spa mode. I know there is no browser localsotorage in the server.

If any user is logged in, I do not want him/her to visit the main home page. But when I built my app in SSR mode as usually this function is useless and for that, it takes the user to the home page.

In SSR mode is there any way to prevent users from visiting the main homepage if they are logged in?

Comment: use cookie instead

Comment: you should look into this instead https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action